# How do I get a button to return a value?

Tags: java, jtextfield, jradiobutton

I am writing a program to simulate voting districts for the electoral college. I am having trouble getting the logic to work to calculating the votes when the JRadioButton for a respective party is selected as well as printing the total votes for each party to a TextField to display it.

```
public ElectoralCollegeGUI()
{
    super("Cast Your Votes");
    //JPanel mainGridPanel = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new GridLayout(14,8));


    String[] state = {"Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut","Delaware", 
              "Florida" , "Georgia" ,"Hawaii","Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine 1st", 
              "Maine 2nd" ,"Maine Popular","Maryland", "Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri", 
              "Montant",   "Nebraska 1st",   "Nebraska 2nd",   "Nebraska 3rd", "Nebraska Popular", "Nevada","New Hampshire",
              "New Jersey",   "New Mexico","New York",   "North Carolina", "North Dakota",   "Ohio",   "Oklahoma",
              "Oregon",   "Pennsylvania",   "Rhode Island",   "South Carolina",   "South Dakota",
              "Tennessee",   "Texas",  "Utah",  "Vermont",  "Virginia",  "Washington",
              "West Virginia",  "Wisconsin",  "Wyoming",  "Washington,D.C.",};  

    String[] voteValue = { "9","3","11","6","55","9","7","3","29","16","4","4","20","11","6",
                        "6","8","8","1","1","2","10","11","16","10","6","10","3","1","1","1",
                        "2","6","4","14","5","29","15","3","18","7","7","20","4","9","3","11",
                        "38","6","3","13","12","5","10","3","3"};



    for ( int i = 0; i < 56 ; i++)
    {
        add(new VoteChoice(state[i] , voteValue[i]));
    }

}
    private class VoteChoice extends JPanel
    {
        public VoteChoice(String state, String voteValue)
        {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            JLabel StateName = new JLabel(state);
            JLabel StateValue = new JLabel(voteValue);
            JTextField demoTotal = new JTextField();
            JTextField repTotal = new JTextField();
            JTextField undTotal = new JTextField();

            demoTotal.setText(getDemoVoteCount());
            repTotal.setText(getRepVoteCount());
            undTotal.setText(getUndVoteCount());


            ButtonGroup party;
            party = new ButtonGroup();

            Democrat = new JRadioButton("Democrat");
            Republican = new JRadioButton("Republican");
            Undecided = new JRadioButton("Undecided");

            //adds buttons to party button group
            party.add(Democrat);
            party.add(Republican);
            party.add(Undecided);

            add(demoTotal, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            add(repTotal, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            add(undTotal,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

            add(StateName, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            add(StateValue,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            add(Democrat, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            add(Republican, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            add(Undecided, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);



            VoteSelected listener = new VoteSelected();
            Democrat.addItemListener(listener);
            Republican.addItemListener(listener);
            Undecided.addItemListener(listener);

        }//end vote choice constructor

            private class VoteSelected implements ItemListener
            {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
                {
                    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    {
                        if(e.getSource() == Democrat)
                        {
                            //code to get what state was selected
                            //code to calculate vote based on what state was selected. 
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }//end voteChoice contructor

}//ends main class
```

The above is my current code for the GUI. What I have tried as far is:

```
private class VoteSelected implements ItemListener
            {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
                {
                    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    {
                        if(e.getSource() == Democrat)
                        {
                            if(Democrat.isSelected() == true)
                            {
                                whatState = state; //gets state name
                                String numDemoVotesString = voteValue; //gets numb of votes as String
                                int numDemoVotesInt = Integer.parseInt(numDemoVotesString); //converts numb votes from String to int.
                                demoVoteCount = demoVoteCount + numDemoVotesInt;
                            }
                            else if(Democrat.isSelected() == false)
                            {
                                whatState = state; //gets state name
                                String numDemoVotesString = voteValue; //gets numb of votes as String
                                int numDemoVotesInt = Integer.parseInt(numDemoVotesString); //converts numb votes from String to int.
                                demoVoteCount = demoVoteCount - numDemoVotesInt;
                            }
                            return demoVoteCount;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

After which I have a public class to getDemoVoteCount that will return as string that I will pass into the TextField. But the issue is the button logic is not correct. Can someone please help me fix my methodology or suggest something that might work better.

Comment: Instead of return demoVoteCount set it to a variable in a another singleton class which you can keep updating and use that for viewing.

Comment: Something like this?                                                                                  String getDemoVoteCount()
 {
  String displayDemoTotal = Integer.toString(demoVoteCount);
  return displayDemoTotal;
 }